# Making col-auto the same width between multiple rows

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Lets say I have the following rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 longest one</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 longest one</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 shorter</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 shorter</div>
</div>
```

This produces:

[image]

What I am looking to achieve:

[image]

What approach could I take to ensure the columns maintain the same widths between these different rows, so that they all become the width of the largest column?

Comment: There is no way using col-auto. Use tables, CSS grid or [set col widths as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525211/cannot-get-bootstrap-4-horizontal-form-to-work-as-required/50625702#50625702)

Answer (score 13):

You can try `display:table` like this:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
}

.container>.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.container>.row>* {
  display: table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
.col {
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 longest one</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 longest one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 shorter</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Using a table which is set to fill the entire width. Have set col1 to take up all the space avaliable. Because its a table, the other 2 columns will just work.
Have set the text in the table cells to not wrap so you can see it working fluidly.

```css
.custom-table {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.col-wide {
    width: 100%;
}

.row td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-wide">Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-wide">Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 longest one ffdssdgg</td>
    <td>Row 3 longest one</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="row">
    <td class="col-wide">Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 shorter</td>
    <td>Row 3 shorter</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any questions, shout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `display: grid`.

And after you can style your rows as you want.

```css
.container>.row {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 50% auto auto;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 longest one</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 longest one</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 shorter</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If You add more text to second column in any of rows it will break. Since all 3 rows are separate and do not react to columns sizes in other rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use grid display :

```
    <style>
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto ;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.grid-container > div {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
</style>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3</div>
  </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 longest one</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 longest one</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Row 1</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 2 shorter</div>
    <div class="col-auto">Row 3 shorter</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use col-sm-* instead of col-auto.

Comment: how should this help? `col-sm-*` is not even a valid bootstrap class

Answer (score -3):

use table with no border, for example like this:

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2</td>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>


<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 longest one</td>
    <td>Row 3 longest one</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 shorter</td>
    <td>Row 3 shorter</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Yeah but what if I want this to work with multiple tables on the same page as well?

Comment: use css class on td element ex: <td class="col-auto">, and create "col-auto" css class which contains width="auto".