# Cannot get Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Form to work as required

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

How do I make a simple [Bootstrap Horizontal Form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#horizontal-form) that looks correct on phone, tablet and computer. Namely I want the combos to be aligned as shown in the example, but I don't want the combos larger than necessary, and I only want a small gap between label and combo. Then when screen size is too small to fit in label and combo I want them stacked.

Specifically the Boostrap example use up the whole 100% width I dont want that, I don't want the combo to be wider then necessary and I dont want a big gap between the label and the combo.

I tried adding *col-auto* but then the combos no longer horizontally aligned with each other.

I have now tried adding col-[1-12] values for label and combo as described in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#column-sizing but then it didnt stack correctly when goes to small phone.

I then tried using col-md so the totals less than 12 but it doesn't look right on main screen because now both the label and combo take the same space so they have half the screen each and are nowhere near each other.

```html
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div>
     <div class="form-row">
         <label for="discogsGenreOverwriteOption" id="discogsGenreOverwriteOptionlabel" class="col-form-label col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
             Genre
         </label>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
             <select aria-describedby="discogsGenreOverwriteOptionhelp" class="custom-select" name="discogsGenreOverwriteOption" id="discogsGenreOverwriteOption">
                 
                     <option value="0">
                         Always replace values
                     </option>
                     <option value="1">
                         Always add values
                     </option>
                     <option value="2">
                         Replace if empty
                     </option>
                     <option selected="selected" value="3">
                         Never Replace
                     </option>
                 
             </select>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-row">
         <label for="discogsGenreFromOption" id="discogsGenreFromOptionlabel" class="col-form-label col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5">
             From
         </label>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
             <select aria-describedby="discogsGenreFromOptionhelp" class="custom-select" name="discogsGenreFromOption" id="discogsGenreFromOption">
                 
                     <option value="0">
                         Discogs Style
                     </option>
                     <option value="1">
                         Discogs Genre
                     </option>
                     <option value="2">
                         Discogs Style and Genre
                     </option>
                 
             </select>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it the responsive between label & combo-box is what you want? 
If you do not want the big gap, you may need to change value of label. May you take a look at this
https://jsfiddle.net/jzmrgxdo/2/

Comment: @ToanLu I dont want that big gap and i dont want the gap size to change as the screen size changes, by value do you mean the label text well I cant change the label just to fix the gap especialy since the siet is internationalized.

Comment: what exaclty do you want the labels and selects to be same for all screens??

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I want to look exactly like the Boostrap Horizontal Form example so there are two rows and the combos are horizontally aligned and as the screen is made smaller nothing  chnages except the combo gets smaller, until there is not enough room for label and combo on same row they are stacked. But the one difference I want is that the combo is only the width required for the data rather than being whole width of the available space.

Comment: This will eliminate the gap between label & combo box, you can then change the value of bootstrap column for the combox box based on the screen size.
https://jsfiddle.net/jzmrgxdo/9/

Comment: @ToanLu not ist not aligning combos horzizontally, clearer with longer label see https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/jzmrgxdo/10/ . The correct an amendedment to Bootstraps horizontal form example rather than doing completely different way

Comment: Oh, I know what you want now. 
In that case, I think you need to create two column. One with label only & one with input only.

Comment: @ToanLu could you do an example please

Comment: @PaulTaylor https://jsfiddle.net/jzmrgxdo/11/ Here you are. I think this is what you need

Comment: @ToanLu Unfortunately not, looks okay on main screen but when you make screen very small so the items are vertically stacked it goes label, label, combo, combo instead of label, combo, label, combo. You have created new line classes but i want to work within Bootstrap4, I think i need a Boostrap4 expert.

Comment: @PaulTaylor You can create another label layout on the input column & then in small screen you will hide `label-column` & show the `input-column` with all the label being hidden on large screen.
You can always use bootstrap for what you wanted anyway.

Comment: Thanks for trying but no that is far too hacky, Im sure there is an elegant solution to this problem

Comment: You're welcome. I am also looking forward to that solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that Flexbox doesn't work in rows/columns the way a Table does. You can use `col-sm-auto` to get each label to shrink-to-fit, but then the labels/inputs won't align vertically down the page...

[image]

It sounds like you want to **shrink the label column to fit the width of the widest label**. This could be done by putting all the labels in 1 column, and inputs in another column, but then each label/input won't stack together on mobile screens.

There's no elegant Bootstrap-only solution to this problem. You can use Tables, CSS grid, or the option described by @Toan Lu in the comments.

**Bootstrap Grid option**

I'd recommend simply using `col-sm-2` or `col-sm-3` for the labels (fitting them to approx. the widest label) and `text-truncate` to ellipsis(...) the overflowing text until they stack vertically on mobile...

[image]

```
<div class="form-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 text-truncate">
            Label
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
             <select>..</select>
        </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/e3mDrmMv7k

---

**Table option**

With this option, the `width:1%` is used on the labels so that they shrink to the width of the widest. Use `text-nowrap` to stop the labels from wrapping. Each form row is a `d-table-row` and each label is a `d-table-cell`...

```
.col-form-label.d-sm-table-cell {
   width: 1%;
}
<div class="container py-3">
    <div class="form-row d-table-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 d-sm-table-cell text-nowrap">
            Genre
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <select>
             ..
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row d-table-row">
        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 d-sm-table-cell text-nowrap">
            Longer label here
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
            <select>
                ..
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/e3mDrmMv7k (see 2nd option)

The table option makes the divs into tr/td but also works responsively allowing the fields to stack vertically on mobile. Read more on [d-table classes](Yes, part of Bootstrap 4: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#notation).

---

**CSS Grid option**

One other (non-Bootstrap 4) method is using CSS grid. Make the row `display:grid` Use the `fr` sizing on the 2 `grid-template-columns` across the row.

```
.d-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr;
}
```

https://codeply.com/go/9Z7Hg2tl1H

Comment: I'm kind of shocked that Bootstrap cant do this easily considering the amount of fanfare regarding its reponsiveness and that I am using Bootstrap 4. I always used to use tables but they are not suited from going from two cols to one col, one reason I moved to Bootstrap, Toans comments were pure hacks and didn't work. CSS grid may work (I havent learned how to use it yet), why doesn't Bootstrap to use that.

Comment: A solution using Table Grid would be my preferred option rather than trying to shoehorn Boostrap Layout to do something it is not (for whatever reason) intended to do.

Comment: Interesting when you said table i thought you meant tr/td but the solution you have added may work for me, but in unclear is d-table-row, d-table-cell part of Bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes, part of Bootstrap 4: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#notation -- making the divs into tr/td but also works responsively allowing the fields to stack vertically on mobile.

Comment: You mean makes them ACT AS tr/tds, okay thanks looks like that willwork I will award you the bounty

Answer (score -1):

Works as expected if you use earlier version of bootstrap css:

```
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: So is this a bug in Bootstrap4 then (BTW I am  committed to Bootstrap 4 so I cannot use Bootstrap 3) ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor | Bootstrap4 does not have `form-horizontal`.
I'm not sure if this is a "bug" or a reduction of non-nonsensical terms.

For example - neither `btn-default` or `col-xs-NN` exist in BSv4.

Comment: Another example is that you can't use `list-group-item success` but need to now use `list-item-group list-group-item-success`.

In other words, many things have changed.  And, BTW ~ I've only this week begun using Bootstrap for the first time ever and I'm already deeply aware of v1 ~ v4 differences.

Comment: here ya go!
[Bootstrap 4 Migration](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/)