# Bootstrap 4 form inline elements - align centers

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4

What is the best way to align end of one inline form element and the start of another one? 
In flex containers the width value can't be respected by definition, so I am not sure how to tackle this!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    .col {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <form>
        <div class="form-inline input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="TypeB">Type B</label>
            </div>
            <select class="custom-select" id="TypeB">
                <option value="Type B">Type B</option>
            </select>

            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="TypeBDetail">Type B detail</label>
            </div>
            <input id="TypeBDetail" type="text" class="form-control" >
        </div>


        <div class="form-inline input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="Number1">Number1 title is here          </label>
            </div>
            <input id="Number1" type="text" class="form-control" >

            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="number"> number</label>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="number" class="form-control" >

        </div>

        <div class="form-inline input-group mb-2">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="textarea1">Textarea1</label>
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea1" rows="4" ></textarea>

            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <label class="input-group-text" for="textarea2">Text<br/>area2</label>
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea2" rows="4" ></textarea>
        </div>

      </form>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if you use columns for better layout and extra padding between inputs?

Comment: @JakubMuda will try!

Comment: I've answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50525211/cannot-get-bootstrap-4-horizontal-form-to-work-as-required/50625702#50625702) before.

Comment: @Zim and how would you extrapolate your answer to a situation where you have an inline form?

Comment: @JakubMuda doesn't work.