# Wrapping grid in bootstrap with different column sizes

Tags: css, css-grid, bootstrap-5

I’d like to set up a page with multiple entries consisting of some description text and associated icons. The icons may vary in size and should be aligned. (I use letters “i” and “w” instead of icons for simplicity in my examples below.)

When the page is wide enough, I’d like them to be set up as a grid with a wide left column and the icons to the right, that should take as few horizontal space as possible. Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/oliviercailloux/pen/MWmgVaN) with two “icons”.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, max-content);
}
.content {
    justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Some text</div>
    <div class="content">i</div>
    <div class="content">i</div>
    <div class="header">Some more text</div>
    <div class="content">w</div>
    <div class="content">w</div>
</div>
```

When the viewport is too small, so that the left column would be reduced, say, below 200 px, I’d like to switch responsively the layout and have it displayed as a stack, as in [this example](https://codepen.io/oliviercailloux/pen/jOmNzpN).

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, max-content) 1fr;
}
.container > div {
    justify-self: center;
}
.header {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 5;
}
.content1 {
    grid-column-start: 2;
}
.content2 {
    grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">Some text</div>
    <div class="content1">i</div>
    <div class="content2">i</div>
    <div class="header">Some more text</div>
    <div class="content1">w</div>
    <div class="content2">w</div>
</div>
```

This approach works, but there are multiple aspects that I’d like to improve, if possible.

- My web site uses bootstrap, so I could use their “row” and “col” functionalities (or other bootstrap concepts). Designing my own grid instead feels like not using the right tools for the job. But I could not find out how to design such a grid with bootstrap’s rows and columns. ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67890534) raises a similar problem.)
- My approach requires an explicit media query and uses two completely different designs depending on the available space. This feels more complex than necessary. Is it possible to make better use of the grid module responsiveness (or any other appropriate html or css trickery), so that the icons would automatically flow below the text when the viewport is too small? I thought about using auto-fill, but as my columns do not all have the same size, I ignore how to proceed.
- My current design for the small viewport case uses classes `content1`, `content2`, and so on, and repetitive CSS instructions to place them in successive columns. This problem will be exacerbated if I want more icons. Can I avoid such repetition?

Answer (score 0):

The [display classes are responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#notation). Therefore you can use `d-flex d-md-grid` on the container. When it switches to `display:flex` the grid-template-columns will be ignored.

```
.container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(2, max-content);
}
.content {
    justify-self: center;
}

<div class="container d-flex d-md-grid flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center text-md-start text-center">
    <div class="header w-100">Some text</div>
    <div class="content">i</div>
    <div class="content">i</div>
    <div class="header w-100">Some more text</div>
    <div class="content">w</div>
    <div class="content">w</div>
</div>
```

[Demo on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/iKhnrAPP5Y)

Of course, you could use `d-sm-grid`, `d-lg-grid` or `d-xl-grid` instead of `d-md-grid` to set the breakpoint as desired.

Comment: This does wonder for the “big size” case, but not for the small one: I get the i’s and the w’s on different rows (each one on its own row), whereas I want the i’s next to each other, on a single row (and similarly for the w’s), as my example shows. Any idea about how to do that?

Comment: Fairly easy to accommodate my changing the flex direction and wrap. Updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, but the “small size” case is still not exactly right: the i’s are not column-aligned on the w’s. I ignore how to achieve this properly (see the end of my question).